# Message History Request Returns Empty Result

Tags: xml, xmpp, monitoring, openfire

I use the following stanza to get the history messages :

```
<iq type='get' id='user1'>
  <list xmlns='urn:xmpp:archive'
        with='admin@localhost'>
    <set xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/rsm'>
      <max>30</max>
    </set>
  </list>
</iq>
```

And The response is :

```
<iq id="user1" to="user1@localhost/Smack" type="result"></iq>
```

Although I can see the messages between the two users on the Openfire Admin Console.. I use Monitoring Service..

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to create your own provider.. Like that:

```
public class HistoryIQProvider implements IQProvider {
public static final String NAMESPACE = "urn:xmpp:archive";
public static final String ELEMENT_NAME = "list";
public static final String CHAT = "chat";
public static final String START_TIME = "start";

private ArrayList<String> startTimes = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
public IQ parseIQ(XmlPullParser parser) throws Exception {
    boolean stop = false;
    String name = parser.getName();
    Log.d("Parse", "Name: " + name);

    while(false == stop)
    {
        switch (parser.getEventType())
        {
            case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
            {
                if(ELEMENT_NAME.equals(name)) {

                    /*** START_TAG = 2
                     ***  END_TAG = 3
                     ***/

                    while (parser.nextTag() == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                        /*** Stop when chats is finished.. ***/
                        if(parser.getName().equals("set")) {
                            break;
                        }
                        String startTime = parser.getAttributeValue(1);
                        startTimes.add(startTime);
                        parser.nextTag();
                    }
                }
            }
            case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
            {
                stop = ELEMENT_NAME.equals(name);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    name = null;
    HistoryIQ historyIQ = new HistoryIQ(startTimes);
    return historyIQ;
}
}
```

HistoryIQ :

```
public class HistoryIQ extends IQ {
private ArrayList<String> startTimes = new ArrayList<String>();

public HistoryIQ(ArrayList<String> l) {
    startTimes = l;
}

@Override
public String getChildElementXML() {
    return null;
}

public ArrayList<String> getHistory_Chats() {
    Log.d("Parse", "Lists : " + startTimes.size());
    return startTimes;
}
}
```